# ContourPlot for a certain value

Tags: plotting, complex

Consider this example:

```
f[x_] := -I*2*x + 3*x^2
```

which is a complex function defined on a complex plane $x=x_r+ix_i$

It is convenient to plot the contour of its real part Re[f] with

```
ListContourPlot[Re[Table[ComplexExpand[f[xr + I*xi]], {xr, 0, 0.2, 0.01}, {xi, -0.05,
 0.05, 0.001}]]]
```

But sometimes we want to only show the contour for **a certain value with a legend for the specific value**. For example, how can I only plot the contour for Re[f]=0 with a legend for it?

I naively tried as follows, but it didn't work.

```
ListContourPlot[Re[Table[ComplexExpand[f[xr + I*xi]], {xr, 0, 0.2, 0.01}, {xi, -0.05,
  0.05, 0.001}]] == 0]
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: How about `ContourPlot[
 Re[ComplexExpand[f[xr + I*xi]]] == 0, {xr, 0, 0.2}, {xi, -0.05, 
  0.05}]`

Comment: @Chris, it can do this, but for some cases when we do not have an analytical function $f$, it is expected that we can plot with `ListContourPlot`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
  ff = Re[Table[{xr, xi, ComplexExpand[f[xr + I*xi]]}, {xr, 0, 0.2, 
  0.01}, {xi, -0.05, 0.05, 0.001}]] // Flatten[#, 1] & //Interpolation
```

[image]

Then

```
  ContourPlot[ff[xr, xi] == 0, {xr, 0, 0.2}, {xi, -0.05, 0.05}]
```

[image]

As requested by OP, 'ff' could be written as

```
   ff = Interpolation [Flatten[Re[Table[{xr, xi, ComplexExpand[f[xr +I*xi]]}, 
  {xr, 0, 0.2,  0.01}, 
 {xi, -0.05, 0.05, 0.001}]], 1]]
```

Comment: thanks! It works. You created a pure function. Well, could you make it without the postfix form using `//Interpolation` if it is possible?

Answer (score 5):

```
f[x_] := -I*2*x + 3*x^2
```

Since you are taking the real part, [`ComplexExpand`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexExpand.html) is not necessary. To get a specific contour, just specify the contour.

```
ListContourPlot[
 Table[{xr, xi, Re@f[xr + I*xi]},
   {xr, 0, 0.2, 0.01}, {xi, -0.05, 0.05, 0.001}] //
  Flatten[#, 1] &,
 Contours -> {{0}},
 ContourShading -> None]
```

[image]

Comment: your comment and method are useful as well. But I cannot accept both. I accepted chris' answer because that solved my problem earlier. Sorry about that.

Comment: @user55777  you could  still upvote  this answer? his answer is better since it doesn't rely on unnecessary interpolation.